# How to escaped specific words using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a query string `query_word = platelet NEAR/2 function NEAR/2 testing)) AND la.exact("English") AND TI(test or testing OR assay) AND human(yes)`

my output need to be like that `output= platelet NEAR/2 function NEAR/2 testing)) AND AND TI(test or testing OR assay) AND human(yes)`

I want to match the word `la.exact("English")` and delete it.

**PS** the content of `la.exact("content")` can change.

My regular expression is  `\b(la.exact((.*?)\))\b`

Comment: Use [`\bla\.exact\(.*?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/BWy0gk/1)

Comment: Escape the literal parentheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its wrong https://regex101.com/r/rqpmXr/12

Comment: I posted my link, but anyway your question is a dupe.

Comment: And what's the logic for removing: `AND` before `la.exact` ?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande sorry it was my mistake now  the output is correct